# Old Electrum wallet, encoded text document and non-functional seeds

Tags: electrum, wallet-recovery, seed

I am trying to recover an old Electrum wallet that I used to use to buy "things" in college, circa 2016 or so. I remember having 10 to 30 dollars left in it back then that I never thought about until recently. Now it might be worth a couple thousand.

I managed to recover some data from an old, crashed hard-drive which included a text file titled BCwallet. This file appears to contain information about my wallet in a format that appears similar to a JSON or CSS file, but it's mostly random numbers and letters. For example the file starts off with

```
{
    "accounts": {
        "0": {
            "change": [
                "03522bfc10eab4e91d310b0825c4f50e297c64b991d8e320d2dd96528d9a64df6b",...
```

The file does have headings "seed" and "Master private key," but these are followed by the same encoded nonsense.

Does anyone recognize the format of the above string and how I could convert it to something readable?

With some digging I managed to find an old notebook from that era with info that I recognize as relating to these endeavors. This includes two 13 word strings (seeds were 13 words back then). I vaguely remember jotting them down when I created my wallet, and having to try again for some reason, thus having two. Both strings only contain words available in Electrum's seed creation dictionary.

Anyway, I tried using these to recover my old wallet via [this guide.](https://bitcoinelectrum.com/restoring-your-standard-wallet-from-seed/) For one of the seeds, when I get it all entered the "next" button lights up, I click it, and it opens an empty wallet with no transaction history, even after switching servers. For the other seed the "next" button stays grayed over and is not clickable. I have checked spelling 100%. These were both originally Electrum created seeds and should not be BIP39, though I have tried that without luck as well.

I can feel I'm on the cusp of a nice little payday. Does anyone have any ideas of what else I could try with the information I have?

Thanks a ton for any help!

Comment: Nevermind. I just opened the text file through electrum's menu and it opened my old wallet!